# Find minimum of n Elements with log(n) comparisons per element

Tags: algorithm, search, selection, minimum

I need to write an algorithm that finds the minimum of n elements with:

1. n-1 comparisons.
2. Performing only log(n) comparisons per element.

I thought of the selection search algorithm, but I think it compares each element more than log(n) times.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of a selection process as a tournament:

1. The first element is compared to the second, the third to the fourth and so on.
2. The winner of a comparison is the smaller element.
3. All the winners participate in the next round, in the same manner, until one element remains. The remaining element is the smallest of all.

### Pseudocode

I'll give the recursive solution, but you can implement it iteratively also.

```
smallestElement(A[1...n]):
    if size(A) == 1:
        return A[1]
    else
        return min(smallestElement(A[1...n/2], smallestElement(A[n/2 + 1...n]))
```

The recursion has depth logn because on every level we dividing the size of the input by 2, so the winner of the tournament participates in logn comparison, and no one element participates in more comparisons.